# memory management for a value and reference type

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have searched about the subject of `reference type vs value type in C#` and data allocation in stack and heap.

From these sources , [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap) and [this article](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html), I make this conclusion :

- The value of reference type is stored on the heap, and the adress of this value is stored on the stack
- A value type is stored on the stack
- Local variables of running function are stored in the stack
- Global variables are stored on the heap

I have few questions :

1. If I had a global variable and it is a value type. where it will be stored?
2. If I had a local reference type variable. where it will be stored?
3. Why it is recommended to write this :

   ```
   public class OurClass()
   {
      public ClassA objA;  
      public OurClass()
      {
       objA = new ClassA();
      }
   }
   ```

**Instead of writing**

```
 public class OurClass()
    {
       public ClassA objA = new ClassA(); 
       public OurClass()
       {
         
       }
    }
```

Did it have relation with allocation performance?

Thanks,

Comment: This is not related to C at all. And either it is C# or C++ but it can't be both.

Comment: This may be of interest: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx